# Laravel Insert Seed if data doesn't already exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there any way to run a laravel `seed` to only insert the records if they do not exist already?

My current laravel seeder looks like this

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
                //Global Admin
                [
                    'member_id' => 11111111,
                    'firstname' => 'Joe',
                    'lastname' => 'Bloggs'
                ], 
                [
                    'member_id' => 22222222,
                    'firstname' => 'Jim',
                    'lastname' => 'Bloggs'
                ], 

            ]);
```

Pretty standard!

would I have to wrap each and every insert in a try catch? like this

```
try {
   DB::table('users')->insert(['member_id' => 11111111, 'firstname' => 'Joe', 'lastname' => 'Bloggs']);
} catch(Exception $e){
  //Die silently
}
try {
   DB::table('users')->insert(['member_id' => 22222222, 'firstname' => 'Jim', 'lastname' => 'Bloggs']);
} catch(Exception $e){
  //Die silently
}
```

Later on I might want to add extra rows to the same seeder without having to write a new one, and re run `php artisan db:seed` to only add my new rows.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by Eloquent [firstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods).

> The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record
>   using the given column / value pairs. If the model can not be found in
>   the database, a record will be inserted with the attributes from the
>   first parameter, along with those in the optional second parameter.

So, if you identify the user by member_id, you can do something like this:

```
    User::firstOrCreate(
        ['member_id' => 11111111],
        [
            'firstname' => 'anakin',
            'lastname' => 'skywalker',
            'password' => Hash::make('4nak1n')
        ]
    );
```

If you want to locate the record by 'member_id', 'firstname' and 'lastname' fields, something like this:

```
    User::firstOrCreate(
        [
            'member_id' => 11111111,
            'firstname' => 'anakin',
            'lastname' => 'skywalker'
        ],
        [
            'password' => Hash::make('4nak1n'),
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Seeding is only supposed to be used for testing, anyways.

Why don't you just execute `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`?

This will refresh your database (deletes the tables) then runs all your migrations again and finally seeds the database again.

You should never be using seeders in production.

Just add the new data to your seeder, run `migrate:fresh` and re-seed :)

Comment: I'm using seeders to add default data into the system, so when I first push it to production I don't have to worry about adding loads of data manually. Plus, if I ever push a new feature that has new migrations with default data, I can't run `php artisan db:seed` on the live database, because it throws errors that the default data already exists!

Comment: You would make separate seeders in that case and call `php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder` as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding#running-seeders)

Comment: Note, laravel developers discourage seeding in production by requiring you to use the --force flag.

Answer (score 3):

As [stokoe0990](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848660/stokoe09900) stated, it is not advisable to run seeders in production. The Laravel Seeder was written as way to generate test data. Per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding#introduction) "*Laravel includes a simple method of seeding your database with test data using seed classes*".

That said, The only way you can satisfy your question is to build the logic into your seed:

```php
$users = array(
    ['member_id' => 11111111,'firstname' => 'Joe','lastname' => 'Bloggs'], 
    ['member_id' => 22222222,'firstname' => 'Jim','lastname' => 'Bloggs']
);

foreach ($users as $user) {
  if (\App\User::find($user['id'])) {
    DB::table('users')->insert($user);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're right, this seems like the most logical way unfortunately!

Comment: I would just like to re-iterate that running seeders in production is heavily advised against.

Comment: I'd like to point out that sometimes an application could be needed to be deployed in a new environment for each client and in this case you might want to have a starting point with some data. I often embed seeder in the initial migration for a table to fill some data in production (first deployment only). Just something to think about. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using Eloquent `updateOrInsert()` method:

```
DB::table('users')->updateOrInsert('your_data');
```

Read more about it [here](https://laraveldaily.com/use-updateorcreate-to-run-seeds-at-any-time/).

Comment: I was thinking about doing this method, but what if the user changes their password or data down the line, wont it update it back to the data thats in the seeder?

Answer (score 1):

The best I recommend is to truncate (or delete all) the data in the table anytime you migrate. Try something like this:

```
//data in the table
DB::table('users')->delete(); //or use model like this: User::truncate();

DB::table('users')->insert([
                //Global Admin
                [
                    'member_id' => 11111111,
                    'firstname' => 'Joe',
                    'lastname' => 'Bloggs'
                ], 
                [
                    'member_id' => 22222222,
                    'firstname' => 'Jim',
                    'lastname' => 'Bloggs'
                ], 
            ]);
```

Then there will be no duplications when you run `php artisan db:seed`

Comment: This does not work in cases where the existing data is referenced with restrict ondelete constraint.